# Laravel blade variable not rendered in inline-style attribute in IE

Tags: css, laravel, laravel-blade, vue.js, inline-styles

We are using the Laravel framework in combination with Vue.js for the backoffice.
For the filemanagement we created tiles with the preview and some info we get with an api-call:

```
<div class="image-tile">
    <div class="preview" v-style="background-image: url('@{{tent.files[fileId].path + '/thumb/' + tent.files[fileId].name }}')">
</div>
<div class="info">
    @{{tent.files[fileId].name}}<br/>
    @{{tent.files[fileId].width}} x @{{tent.files[fileId].height}}<br/>
    @{{(tent.files[fileId].size / 1024).toFixed(2)}}KB
</div>
```

While the info is perfectly rendered, the url is not:

```
style="background-image: url('{{file.path + '/thumb/' + file.name }}');"
```

This should be the result (like in chrome and ff)

```
background-image: url('/uploads/flyfish/thumb/example.jpg');
```

Is this default behaviour in Internet Explorer?

Comment: am sure this issue is from `vuejs` not laravel, you should add vuejs in your tags

Comment: Could you clarify? Are you saying that the background-image above is exactly what you find in the DOM after Vue renders it? And does this only happen on IE or does it happen on all browsers?

Comment: @DavidK.Hess that is indeed what I find in the DOM after Vue renders it. All the other values are rendered fine. It happened with the client who uses IE8 and with me, using IE11. A friend who uses IE10 said he didn't encounter the problem. On chrome on ff there were no issues although I have to admin I can't test on backwards compability on all browsers but chrome and ff-users are mostly up to date, I suppose.

Comment: As to IE8 this warning is in the README of the repo: "Note that Vue.js only supports ES5-compliant browsers (IE8 and below are not supported)." As for IE11, there was no error in the Javascript console?

Comment: @DavidK.Hess I just tested it on my home-pc but the same without any error in the console

Comment: Apparently it is a general problem with IE: https://github.com/yyx990803/vue/issues/651 Use `v-style` instead.

Comment: @DavidK.Hess replacing style with v-style does not do the trick unfortunately althought it is written on http://vuejs.org/api/directives.html. So there must be another issue or syntax.

Comment: Can you update your question with what you tried?

Answer (score 2):

Apparently IE causes problems with templating style attributes – see this closed issue:

https://github.com/yyx990803/vue/issues/651

It's recommended to use `v-style` instead:

http://vuejs.org/api/directives.html#v-style

Something like this:

```
<div class="image-tile">
    <div class="preview" v-style="background-image: 'url(' + tent.files[fileId].path + '/thumb/' + tent.files[fileId].name + ')'>
</div>
<div class="info">
    @{{tent.files[fileId].name}}<br/>
    @{{tent.files[fileId].width}} x @{{tent.files[fileId].height}}<br/>
    @{{(tent.files[fileId].size / 1024).toFixed(2)}}KB
</div>
```

Comment: I tried your example as well as other combo's but now there is no style attribute at all in my div.

Comment: Can you reproduce this in a fiddle?

Comment: Too complicated to reproduce for now. I see what I can do tomorrow to simplify